# Timer start event

Tags: c#, forms, timer, draw

I recently started "learning" C#. Currently i am doing a some sort of a game for school project. I want to draw a circle on a form. I added a time every new circle is drawn every 1000 ms on a random place in form. But when i start my form nothing really happens.

namespace Vezba_4
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
  // attempt is when you try to "poke" the circle
    bool attempt = false;
    int xc, yc, Br = 0, Brkr = 0;
    Random R = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

// Br is the number of circles that player has successfully "poked". And Brkr is a total number of circles that have appeared on the game screen. the

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
        SolidBrush cetka = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
        xc = R.Next(15, ClientRectangle.Width - 15);
        yc = R.Next(15, ClientRectangle.Height - 15);
        g.FillEllipse(cetka, xc - 15, yc - 15, 30, 30);
        Brkr++;
        Text = Br + "FROM" + Brkr;
        attempt = false;
        g.Dispose();
        cetka.Dispose();

    }

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (attempt == false)
        {
            if ((e.X - xc) * (e.X - xc) + (e.Y - yc) * (e.Y - yc) <= 225) Br++;
            Text = Br + " FROM " + Brkr++;
        }
        attempt = true;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you start a `Timer`?  When you debug this, is the timer's tick event ever invoked?

Comment: Make sure you're Timer is enabled in it's properties from within the design view

Comment: I noticed that Timer was disabled but when i start the debug nothing again.
@JohnGrabanski

Comment: Well, i tried, to add a timer1.Start(); in my Form1 section. I edited the code. Take a look. :) 
@David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Here's the properties of the timer I used, I dont have a timer.Start() anyway, it's all just your code with the Enabled property set to true, and the interval 1000. [I noticed when I copied nothing happened, but when I set Enabled to true it started to appear.

Answer (score 1):

What is in the InitializeComponent method generated in the designer Form1.Designer.cs?

Is the event handler for the timer tick there?

```
    // 
    // timer1
    // 
    this.timer1.Interval = 1000;
    this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
```

Edit:
For the mousedown would have to confirm that the handler is there in Form.Designer.cs as well:

```
    this.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseDown);
```

Comment: Well, that helped me to start my form. Just now i have a problem with clicking on the circle. When i click on it nothing happens. "Score" is not increased.

Answer (score 0):

You should draw your circle in Form1_Paint. Because it will be drawn only when Paint event fired, and when fired, it looks for Form1_Paint.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    bool attempt = false;
    int xc, yc, Br = 0, Brkr = 0;

    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (attempt == false)
        {
            if ((e.X - xc) * (e.X - xc) + (e.Y - yc) * (e.Y - yc) <= 225) Br++;
            Text = Br + " FROM " + Brkr++;
        }
        attempt = true;
    }

    public void Paaint()
    {
        SolidBrush cetka = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
        Graphics g = CreateGraphics();
        xc = R.Next(15, ClientRectangle.Width - 15);
        yc = R.Next(15, ClientRectangle.Height - 15);
        g.FillEllipse(cetka, xc - 15, yc - 15, 30, 30);
        Brkr++;
        label1.Text = Br + "FROM" + Brkr;
        attempt = false;
        g.Dispose();
        cetka.Dispose();
    }
    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Paaint();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Invalidate();
    }

    Random R = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: You say to use the Paint method, and then you go and still use CreateGraphics.  Ugh.

Comment: And of course, you should enable the timer and set interval 1000ms, by selecting them on the design view, properties tab.